# MS Word 2013. How to fix this style in the ordered list?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I don't understand how to manage(delete) this BLACK square before the ordered list at level 5.
If someone have some ideas please share! 
Thank you!

[Download the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgzi55qndizu1to/sitemap%20-%20Copy.docx)

[image]

Comment: Your choice of File Sharing site is tad NSWF...

Comment: :D sorry but it's for free and fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the Style of that particular outline/numbering level. I was able to get those numbers to show up by highlighting the numbers and switching to a new style. Screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm, but this doesn't actually solve the problem. Try to make a Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V in the notepad and look what is the result of copying the Page, instead of the black boxes it should be the continuing the numbering eg: after 0.1.3.1. ASDF shoud be 0.1.3.1.1. Complex Details

Comment: @Christian I've redone my answer. I hope this one is helpful.

Comment: New link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf2qjju7o28g3xj/REV%20bullet%20list.docx

Comment: The screen you've added changed the things!! Seems that i couldn't select the list with double click. Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: @Christian The numbered list function in Word is not very intuitive and, because the numbers in your file appear as solid black rectangles, it is almost impossible to tell whether or not they are highlighted.